# Facebook PHP API Error code 100: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using version 4.0 of the PHP SDK for Facebook. I've looked around for the better part of the afternoon, but any posts I've found related to my problem have either not worked or involved the use of the older SDK versions.

I'm trying to make a basic GET request to facebook using the FacebookRequest object, but it returns an error code 100 with error message "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API".

In my app settings I've tried enabling the "require appsecret_proof for server API calls", as well as disabling it. Oddly enough, this doesn't change the error I'm receiving.

EDIT: I've double checked my app key, app secret, and access token, they all appear to be correct.

Here's my code:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'Facebook/autoload.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

$app_key = 'MYAPP_KEY';
$app_secret = 'MYAPP_SECRET';

$fb_access_token = "MYACCESS_TOKEN";

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_key,$app_secret);

try {
  $session = new FacebookSession($fb_access_token);
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
    echo "Facebook returned a request exception.";
    exit;
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo "Facebook returned an unspecified exception.";
    exit;
}

try{
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    $response = $request->execute();
    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    // print data
    echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
}catch(FacebookRequestException $e){
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "Raw response: " . $e->getRawResponse();
}
```

I'm at a loss; I've been staring at it for forever and I can't find what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:
1. In your FbApp disable the "require appsecret_proof for server API calls"
2. In your code, after line FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_key,$app_secret);
   add this line: FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);

Comment: perfect. Work for me.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this with the older SDK v.3? I opened a new topic with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535380/facebook-graph-api-issue-with-appsecret-proof-and-php-sdk-v-3-2-3