# Facebook Graph API: issue with appsecret_proof and PHP SDK v.3.2.3

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a strange issue, that appears since yesterday (07/20/2015). My script worked perfectly since August 2014, so nearly a year, but now it rejects working. If I post a picture or a text to Facebook, I get this server error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GraphMethodException: Invalid
>   appsecret_proof provided in the API argument\n  thrown in
>   .../base_facebook.php on line 1329

This is a line in the function *throwAPIException* in the [Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.3)](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk). I know, it has something to do with with the option **Require App Secret** (in Facebook Devs -> Apps -> Settings -> Advanced). This option is deactivated for a year, so maybe I have to add something new to my script?

In [this stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273980/facebook-php-api-error-code-100-invalid-appsecret-proof-provided-in-the-api) I found a hint to add this line while calling:

```
FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);
```

...but this is related to the newer SDK v.4, not to v.3. In my script, I call the SDK v.3 with:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId' => $App_ID, 'secret' => $App_Secret, 'cookie' => true ));
$facebook->setAccessToken($Access_Token);
```

Is there a way to add **enableAppSecretProof** anywhere there? Thanks for helping me! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: in line 918 of the [base_facebook.php](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php) you have to comment these three lines

```
# if (isset($params['access_token']) && !isset($params['appsecret_proof'])) {
# $params['appsecret_proof'] = $this->getAppSecretProof($params['access_token']);
# }
```

That's it.